# How to kill chromedriver.exe through java script

Tags: javascript, node.js, protractor

I'm using Protractor to automate my application, i have a requirement where i need to kill `chromedriver.exe` explicitly.

In java i can use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("TASKKILL /F/IM chromedriver.exe");` 
but how can i achieve this in Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

you can try using using the [Child Process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) part of `node.js` core library, something like:

```
    const exec = require('child_process').exec;
    exec('TASKKILL /F/IM chromedriver.exe', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
      if (error) {
        console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);
        return;
      }
      console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
      console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
    })
```

Comment: Thank you i will try your solution

Answer (score 0):

it doesn't work it if it uses in conf.js - in AfterLaunch

But.. this it's working

```
afterLaunch: () => {
      const { exec } = require('child_process');
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          exec('taskkill /im chromedriver* /f', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
              console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
              console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
              resolve(stdout);
          })
      })
```